# how to start read a file at a specific position

Tags: c, file

> Exercise
>
> Write a program that will compare two text files whose names will be given as a call arguments.
> This comparison should be carried out line by line, printing out on the screen those lines that differ
> from the same line in the other file. Print the lines with its line numbers and names of the file they
> come from. The line numbers should be relative to the beginning of the file, i.e. the first line should
> have the number 1, the second number 2, etc.

I wrote such a program, but I do not understand how to start read this file from a specific line

```
int main(void)
{
   FILE *a = fopen("D:\\lab9.txt");
   FILE *b = fopen("D:\\lab9.1.txt");
   
   int position = 0, line = 1, error = 0;
   
   if(a == NULL || b == NULL)
   {
       perror("Error occured while opening file.");
       exit(0);
   }
    
    
    char x = getc(a);
    char y = getc(b);
    
    while(x != EOF && y != EOF)
    {
       position++;
       
       if(x == '\n' && y == '\n')
       {
           line++;
           pos = 0;
       }
    
    
    if(x != y)
    {
        error++
    }
      x = getc(a);
      y = getc(b);
    
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Zlytherin 
because i have to display which lines are different

Comment: I do not see why you need to jump to a specific line. According to the statement, you need to compare *all* lines and print the line number of those that differ.

Comment: Unless each line is *exactly* the same length, then it's really impossible to "jump" (or seek) to a specific line without reading all previous lines.

Comment: Also note that [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. That is actually very important for the `EOF` checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach would be to **read the file line by line** and start the actual processing when you reach the line that you are looking for:

You can use something like the following to jump to a specific line:

```
char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */

while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
{
    if (count >= lineNumber)
    {
        //process your line in here.
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

---

I do not think you need to jump to a specific line in order to solve that problem. I would personally solve using something like the following :

**IT IS PSEUDO-C - NOT TESTED**

```
    int count = 0;
    char line1[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
    char line2[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */

    int read1 =  fgets(line1, sizeof line1, file1);
    int read2 =  fgets(line2, sizeof line2, file2);
    while (read1 != NULL && read2 != NULL)
    {
        if( strcmp ( line1, line2))
        {
          //lines are different. print line number and other info   
        }
        read1 =  fgets(line1, sizeof line1, file1);
        read2 =  fgets(line2, sizeof line2, file2);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

The previous code is also not handling when files have different number of lines. You should be able to extend yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to handle the content of a file:

- Read it : you always start at the beginning of the file.
- Write it (starting a new file) : as you start a new file, you automatically start at the beginning.
- Append : you add extra content, starting at the end of a file.

As you can see, there is no way to start reading a file from a certain line number, or based on the existing content. The only thing you can do is start reading the file from the beginning and browse through the file until you get at the piece of content you're interested in.

Comment: You can jump to a specific byte in the file. That doesn't help with (variable length) lines, but you don't necessarily have to start at the beginning.